# Laravel passport create token and refresh token

Tags: laravel, passport-jwt

I'm using Laravel and passport on my project.
In my project users can get token in two way.
First with username and password that its OK by passport.
Second with verification code that sent with SMS that its my problem.

I tried `createToken()` method but it will make a personal token without refresh token and **I need to create token with refresh token and specify client id in a controller (without HTTP request).**

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Go through https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#refreshing-tokens. It will help.

Comment: It seems you don't read my question completely. l have another problem. please read bold part.

Comment: Are you using the [password](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#password-grant-tokens) grant type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a package and I'm using that
https://github.com/qiutuleng/laravel-passport-phone-verification-code-grant

It's good.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new controller **AccessTokenController** that extends `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Response;

class AccessTokenController extends \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController
{
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        try {
            //get username (default is :email)
            $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];

            //get user
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $username)->firstOrFail();

            //issuetoken
            $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);

            //convert response to json string
            $content = $tokenResponse->getBody()->__toString();

            //convert json to array
            $data = json_decode($content, true);

            if(isset($data["error"]))
                throw new OAuthServerException('The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials', 401);

            //add access token to user
            $user = collect($user);
            $user->put('access_token', $data['access_token']);
            $user->put('expires_in', $data['expires_in']);
            $user->put('refresh_token', $data['refresh_token']);

            return Response::json(array($user));
        }
        catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { // email notfound
            //return error message
        }
        catch (OAuthServerException $e) { //password not correct..token not granted
            //return error message
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            ////return error message
        }
    }
}
```

You can generate client_id by using following command

```php
php artisan passport:client
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver even after 2 years now :D